# SQL LEFT JOIN TABLE cause some error

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(ORVM.APPID) AS 'Number of VMs', ORAP.ORDERID
    FROM    Order.[VirtualMachine] ORVM,
        Order.[Application] ORAP,
        Order.[ServiceOrder] SO
    WHERE   SO.ORDERID=ORAP.ORDERID AND
        ORAP.APPID=ORVM.APPID
    GROUP BY ORAP.ORDERID
```

---

```
SELECT COUNT(ORVM.APPID) AS 'Number of VMs', ORAP.ORDERID
  FROM  Order.[ServiceOrder] SO,
    Order.[Application] ORAP
  LEFT JOIN Order.[VirtualMachine] ORVM
  ON ORAP.APPID=ORVM.APPID
  WHERE SO.ORDERID=ORAP.ORDERID
  GROUP BY ORAP.ORDERID
```

TABLE NAME: ORAP

```
APPID   ORDERID APPNAME
2   6   A
3   7   B
4   8   C
5   9   D
6   10  E
9   11  F
```

TABLE NAME: ORVM

```
VMID    APPID   VMNAME
4   2   AA-1
5   2   AA-2
6   2   AA-3
33  5   BB-1
34  6   CC-1
35  6   CC-2
36  6   CC-3
37  6   CC-4
38  10  DD-1
39  10  DD-2
40  10  DD-3
41  9   EE-1
```

TABLE NAME: SO

```
ORDERID ORDERNUM    STATUS
6   OR000001    NORMAL
7   OR000002    NORMAL
8   OR000003    NORMAL
9   OR000004    NORMAL
10  OR000005    NORMAL
11  OR000006    NORMAL
```

And I would like to search how many VMs for each APP, SQL 1 output correct, SQL 2 output error. I would  like to find out the reason and make SQL 2 correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your database was more expressive than just "SQL-00: some error".

Comment: `order` is a reserved word. You need to escape it. In standard SQL you would need to write `"Order"` but your SQL dialect seems to use the non-standard square brackets. Try `[Order]` and see if that gets rid of the error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, when it comes to delimited identidfiers, doesn't at least newer MS SQL Server versions accept ANSI SQL's `"`as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you use join, you have to do it always: Do not mix implicit join by using where and join syntax

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ORVM.APPID) AS 'Number of VMs', ORAP.ORDERID
FROM  
    Order.[ServiceOrder] SO 
JOIN
    Order.[Application] ORAP ON SO.ORDERID = ORAP.ORDERID
LEFT JOIN 
    Order.[VirtualMachine] ORVM ON ORAP.APPID = ORVM.APPID
GROUP BY 
    ORAP.ORDERID
```

I am not sure this will solve your error, because you do not add the eror message.